# Using std::set_intersection for multiple vectors within a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, intersection

So I'm currently working on a function within my C++ program where I'm given a vector of (unsorted) vectors. The goal of the function produce a new vector that contains all elements in common between any two vectors.

I thought I understood how to go about it, but it seems that something isn't quite right. My method was first to sort all of the vectors (via `std::sort`), then use `std::set_intersection` to compare every vector to each other and build the resulting vector. The code compiles fine, however whenever this function gets used the program crashes. On top of that it seems to be causing some memory leaks.

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<unsigned> findCommonIDs(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> > allIDs)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> commonIDs;
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> >::iterator itVecVec;
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> >::iterator itVecVec1;
    for (itVecVec = allIDs.begin(); itVecVec != allIDs.end(); it++)
    {
        std::sort(itVecVec->begin(), itVecVec->end());
    }
    for (itVecVec = allIDs.begin(); itVecVec != allIDs.end(); it++)
    {
        for (itVecVec1 = std::next(itVecVec); itVecVec1 != allIDs.end(); it++)
        {
            std::set_intersection(itVecVec->begin(), itVecVec->end(), itVecVec1->begin(), itVecVec1->end(), std::next(commonIDs.begin(),commonIDs.size());
        }
    }
    return(commonIDs);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: If you don't know how to use debugging tools such as breakpoints and stepping through. Then go ahead and add std::cout statements in different areas and see where it crashes and then go from there, most likely you are going outside the bounds of a vector

Comment: `std::set_intersection(start1, end1, start2, end2, std::back_inserter(commonIDs));` As written, you have an iterator that walks off the end of an empty vector, and is busy writing into some random memory.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're awesome man, worked perfectly-- makes total sense too. I just replaced `std::next(commonIDs.begin(),commonIDs.size());` with `std::back_inserter(commonIDs));` and it works like a charm. Thanks again!